# Regex match fix_ed$variable

Tags: regex

I have a document containing patterns `fix_ed$variable`. These patterns always start with `fix_ed$`, but then they can feature a variable number of lowercased letters, digits, and dots. Dots `.` are the only punctuation marks that can appear in my patterns. Moreover, the patterns are always followed by `,` or `)`. Examples:

- `foo,fix_ed$banana,blahblah,` -> I want to match `fix_ed$banana`
- `(fix_ed$apple.1,4foo` -> I want to match `fix_ed$apple.1`
- `,fix_ed$orange)foo` -> I want to match `fix_ed$orange`

etc. What regex can I used to match those patterns? I'm in notepad++ if that matters.

Comment: which language/regex engine? You can probably use `fix_ed\$([^,)]+)` or `fix_ed$([a-z\d.]+)`

Comment: Thank you, it works! If you write an answer I'll be glad to accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Most regex engines

#### Negated character set

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/a2kAt6/1)

```
fix_ed\$([^,)]+)
```

This matches `fix_ed$` followed by any character that isn't `,` or `)` one or more times, capturing the *variable* in a capture group.

#### Accepted character set

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/a2kAt6/2)

```
fix_ed\$([a-z\d.]+)
```

This matches `fix_ed$` followed by any character that is lowecase alpha, numeric, or `.` one or more times, capturing the *variable* into a capture group.

---

## Other options

#### Lookbehind

Some regex engines allow lookbehinds, so you may be able to use one of the following options:

[See first regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/a2kAt6/3)
[See second regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/a2kAt6/4)

```
(?<=fix_ed\$)[^,)]+
(?<=fix_ed\$)[a-z\d.]+
```

#### Reset match

Some regex engines allow match resets `\K` to reset the match (nothing preceding this token will be captured in the overall match).

[See first regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/a2kAt6/5)
[See second regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/a2kAt6/6)

```
fix_ed\$\K[^,)]+
fix_ed\$\K[a-z\d.]+
```